# App crash happening in Aquos phone with API 19 (4.4.2 Android) using PDFium library

Tags: android, pdfium

Before creating the document my app is crashing on this Aquos Phone.

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = pdfiumCore.newDocument(fileDescriptor)
```

Log messages as follow:

> 03-26 10:49:17.281 7289-7289/? D/jniPdfium: Init FPDF library
>   03-26 10:49:17.301 7289-7289/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 7289 
>   03-26 10:49:17.401 251-251/? I/DEBUG: *****               
>   03-26 10:49:17.401 251-251/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'KDDI/SHL25_jp_kdi/SHL25:4.4.2/S5290/01.00.00:user/release-keys'
>   03-26 10:49:17.401 251-251/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
>   03-26 10:49:17.401 251-251/? I/DEBUG: pid: 7289, tid: 7289, name: my.mobile.com  >>> com.my.mobile.app <<<
>   03-26 10:49:17.401 251-251/? I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 4009d42d  r3 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     r4 6ce5d850  r5 6bd82f98  r6 6ce5d850  r7 6d935f18
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     r8 00000000  r9 6ce12ebc  sl 70a89bd1  fp beb36250
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     ip 70c4ad48  sp beb361c8  lr 70952f80  pc 400af4e0  cpsr 600b0030
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     d0  2f6d65747379732f  d1  644b2f73746e6f66
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     d2  45726f6c6f436964  d3  6674742e696a6f6d
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     d4  a0772300e5712300  d5  658523007a812300
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     d6  e58b230034882300  d7  5c9b2300f7942300
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     d8  0000000000000000  d9  4487000000000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     d10 0000000044d4a000  d11 0000000000000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     d16 2e1e2800c8152800  d17 7d2c280021242800
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     d18 ffcc27000aca2700  d19 d3d4270002d22700
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     d20 50df27006ad82700  d21 80f12700dbe52700
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     d22 d201280020fa2700  d23 390e28009e062800
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     d24 bf2a003812813f9f  d25 3fb74a79a0259813
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     d26 3fe1a66649c97a20  d27 bf56bfae8761967e
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     d28 3fe792c024f3c5ee  d29 bfb752bb4442d180
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     d30 3fd3785be9d52647  d31 3ff7accfa0000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     scr 60000013
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG: backtrace:
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     #00  pc 000234e0  /system/lib/libc.so (strlen+83)
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     #01  pc 00195f7c  /data/app-lib/com.my.mobile.app-1/libmodpdfium.so (CFPF_SkiaFontMgr::ReportFace(FT_FaceRec_, CFPF_SkiaFontDescriptor*)+40)
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     #02  pc 00195ed4  /data/app-lib/com.my.mobile.app-1/libmodpdfium.so (CFPF_SkiaFontMgr::ScanFile(CFX_ByteStringC const&)+264)
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     #03  pc 0019527c  /data/app-lib/com.my.mobile.app-1/libmodpdfium.so (CFPF_SkiaFontMgr::ScanPath(CFX_ByteStringC const&)+456)
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG: stack:
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb36188  6d935f38
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb3618c  6bd86060
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb36190  6d935f18
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb36194  4009d073  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+4254)
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb36198  00000021
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb3619c  23d9d80c
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361a0  00000021
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361a4  00000021
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361a8  400d6000  /system/lib/libc.so
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361ac  6ce5d850
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361b0  6bd82f98
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361b4  6ce5d850
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361b8  6d935f18
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361bc  40099d75  /system/lib/libc.so (free+12)
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361c0  00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.501 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361c4  70952f78  /data/app-lib/com.my.mobile.app-1/libmodpdfium.so (CFPF_SkiaFontMgr::ReportFace(FT_FaceRec_*, CFPF_SkiaFontDescriptor*)+36)
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     #00  beb361c8  6bcd1200
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          ........  ........
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     #01  beb361c8  6bcd1200
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361cc  00000020
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361d0  6ce5d850
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361d4  6d935f18
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361d8  6bd82f98
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361dc  70952ed8  /data/app-lib/com.my.mobile.app-1/libmodpdfium.so (CFPF_SkiaFontMgr::ScanFile(CFX_ByteStringC const&)+268)
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     #02  beb361e0  6bd82f98
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361e4  00000004
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361e8  00000012
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361ec  6cd65f4c
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361f0  6ce12ebc
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361f4  40099d75  /system/lib/libc.so (free+12)
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361f8  00006674
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb361fc  70974ef4  /data/app-lib/com.my.mobile.app-1/libmodpdfium.so (CFX_ByteString::ConcatInPlace(int, char const*)+96)
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb36200  6cd65f4c
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb36204  ec4de9a7
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb36208  beb3628c  [stack]
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb3620c  beb36254  [stack]
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb36210  6dde1008
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb36214  beb3625c  [stack]
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb36218  70a8a116  /data/app-lib/com.my.mobile.app-1/libmodpdfium.so
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          beb3621c  beb36258  [stack]
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:          ........  ........
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG: memory near r2:
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     4009d40c f502d503 f7fd70e0 4628eb6a 81f0e8bd
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     4009d41c 0003ce60 0003cdd4 0003cd92 0003cd88
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     4009d42c 4607b5f8 f0002800 f1a08273 f8df0408
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     4009d43c 447804e8 31bcf8d0 d406079b 54dcf8df
>   03-26 10:49:17.511 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     4009d44c 692e447d d20742b4 f500e236 f7fd70e0
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     4009d45c 2800eac4 bdf8d0f2 1c04f857 0003f001
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     4009d46c f0002801 f0218229 07c90207 0302eb04
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     4009d47c 80b1f100 1c08f857 b9701a64 46203110
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     4009d48c 4631188e e8d8f00f f0402800 f8d5821e
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     4009d49c 1b8201b0 21b0f8c5 42b4e217 f0c0440a
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     4009d4ac 6968820b f0004284 08cf808c d8272f1f
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     4009d4bc eb0568a0 f10505c7 68e10c28 d0064560
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     4009d4cc f0c042b0 68c5820e f04042a5 4281820a
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     4009d4dc f8dfd10a 2501044c fa054478 6801f707
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     4009d4ec 0507ea21 e0766005 d0064561 f0c042b1
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     4009d4fc 688d81fc f04042a5 60c181f8 e06a6088
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG: memory near r4:
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d830 5364696f 48736e61 65726265 65522d77
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d840 616c7567 74742e72 00000066 00000023
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d850 70c48cf8 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d860 00000000 00000000 6d935f18 00000053
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d870 00000000 41400000 3f800000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d880 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d890 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d8a0 00000000 ff000000 00000000 40800000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d8b0 0b000506 66a08020 00000004 00000053
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d8c0 00000000 42380000 3f800000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d8d0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d8e0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d8f0 00000000 ff000000 00000000 40800000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d900 0b000501 66a08020 00000005 00000053
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d910 00000000 41400000 3f800000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d920 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG: memory near r5:
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6bd82f78 4d33f9f0 000000d5 4d49ae73 000000d5
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6bd82f88 6bd796b0 6bd725b8 00750042 0000032b
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6bd82f98 00000001 00000000 00004a1e 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6bd82fa8 00000560 00000000 00000000 00000001
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6bd82fb8 6bd87e48 00000001 6ce32b48 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6bd82fc8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6bd82fd8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6bd82fe8 00000000 6ddc5f00 6ddcac50 6b39c410
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6bd82ff8 6bcc1648 6ce0fc98 6cddd4b8 6bcd2670
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6bd83008 6bcd2670 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6bd83018 6cd66790 74746366 00010000 00000001
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6bd83028 6ce2fed8 00010000 00000009 6cd56d28
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6bd83038 00010000 00010000 3df9a4b7 5f0f3cf5
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6bd83048 0800000b 00000000 cdc2d46b 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6bd83058 cef10c2d fe000000 06000800 00080000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6bd83068 00000002 00000000 00010000 fe000600
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG: memory near r6:
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d830 5364696f 48736e61 65726265 65522d77
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d840 616c7567 74742e72 00000066 00000023
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d850 70c48cf8 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d860 00000000 00000000 6d935f18 00000053
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d870 00000000 41400000 3f800000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d880 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d890 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d8a0 00000000 ff000000 00000000 40800000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d8b0 0b000506 66a08020 00000004 00000053
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d8c0 00000000 42380000 3f800000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d8d0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d8e0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 253-253/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d8f0 00000000 ff000000 00000000 40800000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d900 0b000501 66a08020 00000005 00000053
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d910 00000000 41400000 3f800000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce5d920 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG: memory near r7:
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6d935ef8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6d935f08 00000000 00000000 6ce07900 0000002b
>   03-26 10:49:17.521 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6d935f18 7379732f 2f6d6574 746e6f66 644b2f73
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6d935f28 6f436964 45726f6c 696a6f6d 6674742e
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6d935f38 09060000 00000031 00000000 00000100
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6d935f48 00000000 00000000 00000000 c0000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6d935f58 5a000000 00fe0006 0006b800 00000002
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6d935f68 00000030 0000002a 00000001 00000010
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6d935f78 00000000 00000000 6bd8f918 6de2f048
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6d935f88 6de2f050 6de2f068 00000028 00000023
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6d935f98 00000001 00000005 00000001 00000181
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6d935fa8 77656956 0202a200 00000020 0000001b
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6d935fb8 629ce7e8 0000000e 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6d935fc8 00000001 00000033 3f800000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6d935fd8 00000000 00000000 3f800000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6d935fe8 00000000 00000000 3f800000 00000010
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG: memory near r9:
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce12e9c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce12eac 0000003b 00000001 00000020 00000023
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce12ebc 7379732f 2f6d6574 746e6f66 644b2f73
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce12ecc 6f436964 45726f6c 696a6f6d 6674742e
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce12edc 00000000 00000038 00000023 70c48cf8
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce12eec 6cd2ab38 00000000 00000000 00000003
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce12efc 0000007d 6cd5df00 0000002b 00000001
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce12f0c 0000000d 00000000 00000029 656e694c
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce12f1c 614c7261 74756f79 50001e00 00000100
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce12f2c 00000013 6de33048 00000000 00000010
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce12f3c 00000053 00000000 41400000 3f800000
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce12f4c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce12f5c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce12f6c 00000000 00000000 ff000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce12f7c 40800000 0b000500 66a08020 00000004
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     6ce12f8c 00000053 00000000 41400000 3f800000
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG: memory near sl:
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70a89bb0 36314654 5500482d 534b696e 4654552d
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70a89bc0 562d3631 25584600 00642563 206d6320
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70a89bd0 20002f00 51206f44 3020000a 6a626f20
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70a89be0 3c3c0a0d 7079542f 4f2f2065 74536a62
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70a89bf0 4e2f206d 462f0020 74737269 4c2f0020
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70a89c00 74676e65 3e002068 7274733e 0d6d6165
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70a89c10 462f000a 65746c69 462f2072 6574616c
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70a89c20 6f636544 0d006564 646e650a 65727473
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70a89c30 0a0d6d61 6f646e65 0a0d6a62 20302000
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70a89c40 0d6a626f 2f3c3c0a 65707954 52582f20
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70a89c50 572f6665 3420315b 2f5d3220 65646e49
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70a89c60 5d005b78 7a69532f 2f002065 76657250
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70a89c70 442f0020 646f6365 72615065 3c3c736d
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70a89c80 6c6f432f 736e6d75 502f3720 69646572
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70a89c90 726f7463 3e323120 5258003e 4c006665
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70a89ca0 74676e65 74730068 6d616572 0d000a0d
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG: memory near fp:
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb36230 70a8c49f 70a8a158 70a8c49a 6bcd1200
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb36240 6ce12ebc 00000020 0000000c 6fe809bc
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb36250 6ce12eb0 6ce5d850 00000000 6cd65f40
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb36260 ec4de9a7 6bcd1200 6bcc7a90 6bcc7a90
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb36270 6bcd1200 beb36378 00001164 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.531 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb36280 beb3638c 70952080 6bcd1200 70a8c48c
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb36290 0000000d ec4de9a7 6bcd1200 70951b58
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb362a0 6d9dfde0 6bd8f4b8 beb3638c 70951958
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb362b0 6cdd4328 00000000 70c52288 00000036
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb362c0 beb3638c 70940cf4 00000000 6dd8ec30
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb362d0 00000000 7085e75c 6d0e2010 419ab310
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb362e0 00000000 6d0ce655 6ce56ad8 6d0ce9e3
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb362f0 00000019 00000000 00000000 b872efe8
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb36300 000081b0 00000001 000027e0 00000404
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb36310 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb36320 00001164 00000000 00001000 00000000
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG: memory near ip:
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70c4ad28 70978b04 70853520 70854b94 70854fc4
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70c4ad38 708ec74c 708ed408 708edef8 7097b43c
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70c4ad48 400af48d 400ada44 70855244 708ee4a8
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70c4ad58 708ee464 708ee638 708eb3bc 708edd04
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70c4ad68 708eadd0 709747c0 70975050 708ee0a8
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70c4ad78 7091ab44 7087aabc 7097cd08 7091f8fc
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70c4ad88 7091f924 7087ab6c 7085ef28 70853520
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70c4ad98 7097cf10 709088b8 70941148 7087aad8
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70c4ada8 7097ceb0 70946180 70940c8c 70943990
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70c4adb8 7085371c 40099d7d 7097c66c 400af145
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70c4adc8 40099d69 708ecaf8 7086a54c 70977bd0
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70c4add8 708ed3a0 708ea980 70979850 708ee830
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70c4ade8 70949808 708c4dbc 708c4dec 70949b44
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70c4adf8 708d2df0 70949808 708d288c 7087aabc
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70c4ae08 709498d4 70912a14 708d5074 7094acdc
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70c4ae18 70977c78 70858340 709b2d50 709b2e1c
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG: memory near sp:
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb361a8 400d6000 6ce5d850 6bd82f98 6ce5d850
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb361b8 6d935f18 40099d75 00000000 70952f78
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb361c8 6bcd1200 00000020 6ce5d850 6d935f18
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb361d8 6bd82f98 70952ed8 6bd82f98 00000004
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb361e8 00000012 6cd65f4c 6ce12ebc 40099d75
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb361f8 00006674 70974ef4 6cd65f4c ec4de9a7
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb36208 beb3628c beb36254 6dde1008 beb3625c
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb36218 70a8a116 beb36258 beb36250 70952280
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb36228 0000000c 70a8c4a4 70a8c49f 70a8a158
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb36238 70a8c49a 6bcd1200 6ce12ebc 00000020
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb36248 0000000c 6fe809bc 6ce12eb0 6ce5d850
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb36258 00000000 6cd65f40 ec4de9a7 6bcd1200
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb36268 6bcc7a90 6bcc7a90 6bcd1200 beb36378
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb36278 00001164 00000000 beb3638c 70952080
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb36288 6bcd1200 70a8c48c 0000000d ec4de9a7
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     beb36298 6bcd1200 70951b58 6d9dfde0 6bd8f4b8
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG: code around pc:
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     400af4c0 b31a2b01 0f04f013 800af000 3b04f851
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     400af4d0 3c01f1a3 0c03ea2c 3c80f01c 8033f040
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     400af4e0 2302e8f1 f040f891 3c01f1a2 0c02ea2c
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     400af4f0 3c80f01c 800ff040 3c01f1a3 0c03ea2c
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     400af500 3c80f01c 801ff040 bfeaf7ff 0000eba1
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     400af510 0001f1a0 eba14770 ea5f0000 f040434c
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     400af520 f0808009 ea5f800a f0400c4c f1a08009
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     400af530 47700005 0008f1a0 f1a04770 47700007
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     400af540 0006f1a0 eba14770 ea5f0000 f040434c
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     400af550 f0808009 ea5f800a f0400c4c f1a08009
>   03-26 10:49:17.541 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     400af560 47700001 0004f1a0 f1a04770 47700003
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     400af570 0002f1a0 bf004770 1e0cb510 4807da02
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     400af580 e0034478 d904429c 44784805 f7ef2100
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     400af590 e8bdfb45 f7f14010 bf00ba11 0001efea
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     400af5a0 0001effe b508429a 4805d904 44784903
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     400af5b0 fb34f7ef 4008e8bd b89ef7ff 000138ee
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG: code around lr:
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70952f60 e3550000 13540000 0a000054 e5940004
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70952f70 e5958014 ebfbce98 e1a00008 ebfbce36
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70952f80 e1a07000 e3a00002 e1100f27 1a00004c
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70952f90 e2870001 e3a01001 ebfbce86 e1a06000
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70952fa0 e3560000 1a000001 ebfbce85 e3a06000
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70952fb0 e1a00006 e1a01008 e1a02007 e5846004
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70952fc0 ebfbced3 e3a00000 e7c60007 e595000c
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70952fd0 e3100002 15941008 13811701 15841008
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70952fe0 e3100001 e3a01002 15940008 13800040
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70952ff0 15840008 e5d50008 e3100004 15940008
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70953000 13800001 15840008 e1a00005 ebfbecd5
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70953010 e3a01000 e3500000 0a000022 e5901050
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70953020 e3510000 b5942008 b3822004 b5842008
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70953030 e1d022b0 e6ef3072 e3530002 1a000009
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70953040 e1a02422 e352000d 8a000003 e2422002
>   03-26 10:49:17.551 251-251/? I/DEBUG:     70953050 e6ef2072 e3520007 8a000002 e5942008

```html
03-26 10:49:17.731 888-913/? I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_04 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
03-26 10:49:17.731 888-7404/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.my.mobile.app/.activities.MainActivity
03-26 10:49:17.751 888-5079/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.my.mobile.app (pid 7289) has died.
03-26 10:49:17.751 888-1412/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{4378bac8 u0 com.my.mobile.app/com.my.mobile.app.activities.MainActivity}
03-26 10:49:17.761 888-5079/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendStickyBroadcast:1327 com.android.server.am.UsageStatsService.noteResumeComponent:795 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateUsageStats:3032 com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.reportResumedActivityLocked:2316 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.completeResumeLocked:1027 
03-26 10:49:17.781 888-5079/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1169 com.android.server.am.UsageStatsService$PkgUsageStatsExtended.updateResume:253 com.android.server.am.UsageStatsService.noteResumeComponent:819 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateUsageStats:3032 com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.reportResumedActivityLocked:2316 
03-26 10:49:17.781 1439-1439/? W/FlurryAgent: Start session
03-26 10:49:17.781 1439-1439/? W/FlurryAgent: Event count started: Home_Launch
03-26 10:49:17.841 1439-1439/? I/ActivityManager: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42bca4c8 time:927533
03-26 10:49:17.861 253-253/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
03-26 10:49:18.241 888-904/? I/ActivityManager: Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{434d45c0 u0 com.kddi.android.auhomelauncher/.Launcher t1} time:927938
03-26 10:49:18.551 1439-7409/? W/FlurryAgent: FlurryDataSender: report 412d98ae-e9ec-4dab-bf55-ef783a71cd79 sent. HTTP response: 200 : OK
03-26 10:49:20.281 1149-1149/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshViews: Data not connected!! Set no data type icon / Roaming
03-26 10:49:21.291 1149-1149/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshViews: Data not connected!! Set no data type icon / Roaming
03-26 10:49:22.821 2964-7410/? W/PlatformStatsUtil: Could not retrieve Usage & Diagnostics setting. Giving up.
03-26 10:49:23.301 1149-1149/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshViews: Data not connected!! Set no data type icon / Roaming
03-26 10:49:24.341 7390-7390/? E/RLOG: command timed out pid:7391
03-26 10:49:25.321 1149-1149/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshViews: Data not connected!! Set no data type icon / Roaming
03-26 10:49:27.331 1149-1149/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshViews: Data not connected!! Set no data type icon / Roaming
03-26 10:49:27.991 2964-7410/? W/PlatformStatsUtil: Could not retrieve Usage & Diagnostics setting. Giving up.
03-26 10:49:28.341 1149-1149/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshViews: Data not connected!! Set no data type icon / Roaming
03-26 10:49:29.131 1326-1336/? W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
                                         java.lang.NullPointerException
                                             at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
                                             at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
03-26 10:49:29.131 888-1164/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 7289 uid 10208
```

Share any idea to solve this in API19 on some specific devices.
And the same i tested with HTC of API19 (same Android OS version) the crash does not happen.

How to handle this unexpected termination behavior.

Comment: I don't see anything crash-related in your stacktrace. I think that it is a wrong part of logcat

Comment: Please find the continuation of the log trace added above...